# Target and input must have the same number of elements

Tags: python, pytorch

My input label size is `torch.size([30, 2, 96, 96, 96])`

My labels size is `torch.size([30, 96, 96, 96])`, I am feeding them to my loss function which goes like this :

```
loss = F.binary_cross_entropy(F.sigmoid(output),labels,torch.FloatTensor(CLASS_WEIGHTS).cuda())
```

When I run this, I however get

```
Value error:Target and input must have the same number of elements.target nelement(26542080) != input nelement(53084160)
```

I am a little confused here. I get the input value is twice the target value because it multiplies `[30,96,96]` by the number of classes, but I am not sure why it is so, and how to rectify it. Any suggestions will be helpful, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Unlike the [`torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html?highlight=crossentropyloss#torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss) layer which takes the label values for target (i.e. if `input` is of shape `(30, C, 96, 96, 96)` with `C` number of classes, `target` must be `(30, 96, 96, 96)`), [`torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.binary_cross_entropy) needs `input` and `target` to have the same shape (i.e. `target` of shape `(30, C, 96, 96, 96)`), so it needs the one-hot representation of the target labels.

Unless you go for `torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss`, you have several ways to one-hot your target labels (e.g. see this [thread](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/convert-int-into-one-hot-format/507/25)). A personal solution:

```
def to_one_hot(x, C=2, tensor_class=torch.FloatTensor):
    """ One-hot a batched tensor of shape (B, ...) into (B, C, ...) """
    x_one_hot = tensor_class(x.size(0), C, *x.shape[1:]).zero_()
    x_one_hot = x_one_hot.scatter_(1, x.unsqueeze(1), 1)
    return x_one_hot

# Demonstration:
num_classes = 2
labels = torch.LongTensor(30, 96, 96, 96).random_(0, num_classes)
one_hot_labels = to_one_hot(labels, C=num_classes)
print(one_hot_labels.shape)
# > torch.Size([30, 2, 96, 96, 96])
```